# withCredentials plugin - access values of multiple credentials retrieved

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to figure out how to access the values of multiple credentials retrieved using withCredentials in a Jenkins pipeline.

This is what I am working with currently:

```
def credentialsList = []
def credentials = readJSON text: env.E2E_CREDENTIALS // ['credId-1', 'credId-2']

credentials.each { credential ->
    credentialsList << [$class: 'StringBinding', credentialsId: credential, variable: credentialPwd]
}

withCredentials(credentialsList) {

    // How do I access the retrieved credentialPwd values here?
}
```

I am unsure how to access the list of results, is there a way I can iterate over what has been fetched?

Answer (score 1):

They'll get registered as environment variables, so you'll need to come up with a way of registering them uniquely.  Here's an example of using the index of the credential in the array:

```
def credentialsList = []
def credentials = readJSON text: env.E2E_CREDENTIALS // ['credId-1', 'credId-2']

credentials.each { credential ->
    def index = credentials.findIndexOf { it == [credential] }
    credentialsList << [$class: 'StringBinding', credentialsId: credential, variable: "CREDENTIAL$index"]
}

withCredentials(credentialsList) {
    sh "echo my variable $CREDENTIAL0"
    sh "echo my variable $CREDENTIAL1"
}
```